# An equivalent definition for functions which vanish at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The definitions I'm using are as follows, and I wish to show that they are equivalent:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We say $f$ *vanishes at infinity* if
>
> > $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists K\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, where $K$ is compact, such that $|f(\underline{x})|<\epsilon$, $\forall\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ \ $K$.
>
> We say $\lim_{\||\underline{x}|| \to \infty}f(\underline{x})=0$ if
>
> > $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists M\in[0,\infty)$ such that $\underline{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $||\underline{x}||>M \implies |f(\underline{x})|<\epsilon$.

I think this was meant to be straightforward, but it's not clear to me how to complete the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use first definition to prove second definition.

Fix $\epsilon>0$ first, then by 1st definition we have there exists $K_\epsilon$ compact such that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^N\setminus K$. Now chose $M$ large enough so that $K\subset \overline {B(0,M)}$. Then we have if $x\notin B(0,M)$, $x\notin K$, that is, if $\|x\|>M$, $x\notin K$ and hence $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Now for the converse, fix $\epsilon>0$ and we have $M_\epsilon$ such that if $\|x\|>M_\epsilon$, $|f(x)|<\epsilon$. Set $K:= B(0,M)$, we done.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but a couple questions/concerns: In $\mathbb{R}^n$, I thought compact means closed and bounded? The ball $B(0,M)$ is open. But I think simply changing it to the closed ball will work. Secondly, for the definition of limits above, $M=0$ is a possibility, in which case the open ball will be empty. I think it's okay with a closed ball though; the closed ball will be the singleton ${0}$, which seems fine to me.

Comment: Yes you are right. I will update my answer